# Trapping uninitialized pointers

Tags: c, embedded, rtos

I am trying to trap bad pointers being passed to functions. On a bare metal embedded application I used to use:

```
assert(somePointer != NULL);
```

This worked marginally well, if the particular memory location of the pointer was zero initialised.

I notice that FreeRTOS, and others such as RTX, fill the memory with a pattern such as 0xA5 (to do stack usage high level watermarking). Thus, an unitialised pointer will have some non zero initial value.

Ofcourse, I realise that even a zero initialised memory will become non-zero. As such, I am hoping someone has a better approach for detecting uninitialised pointers.

Since this is an embedded system, I was thinking of having a function check that the pointer is in the correct memory range. On the ST32F4xx that would be 0x20000000 to 0x20020000, or 0x10000000 to 0x10010000 and the peripheral address range as well.

The biggest cause of the unitialised pointers is generally a peripheral handle struct that was declared uninitialised in firmware libraries. The assert() macro used to help detect these as soon as possible.

Suggestions are welcome

Comment: Well, global variables are required by the standard to be `0`/null pointers. For local variables, you should use a compiler which warns about (most) uninitialised usages. Anything else is implementation-specific at best. Checking costs time and code. Often verifying every pointer access manually is just impossble, unless you can tolerate massice penalties (which otoh raise the question why not using a cheaper MCU). And `assert` is only active with `NDEBUG` set. Either way, your question is far too broad.

Comment: Just for argument's sake, an un-init-ed pointer still can point to a meaningful memory address which is not allocated to your process. How about that?

Comment: I'm still surprised that anyone finds this a major problem.  Of all the possible bugs that can happen, dereferencing a null, or other address that is trapped by the memory-management hardware, is not even remotely a big problem, (unless intermittent).

Comment: @Sourav Yes, that is correct. Which is one of the reasons for the question. I was hoping that someone has a brilliant strategy in C for detecting bad pointers and would like to share.

Comment: @Martin I would prefer to have the local code handle the error in a C++ try/catch type manner instead of crashing to the MemFault trap. I may point out as well that by default it appears as though the STM32F4xx series' traps are disabled and thus only result in a generic "Hard Fault". I do enable all the specific traps as well as use the MPU to detect an invalid range of accesses. Note that 0x0 is a valid pointer in the STM32F4xx and can be dereferenced without triggering a memory fault.

Comment: @MartinJames: This has an "embedded"-tag. There is a good chance there will be no "memory managemen hardware". And for a lot of architectures, address `0` is a valid address.

Answer (score 1):

Option one is to do what you are doing: Check for NULL, check that it is in proper address space, check that it is aligned properly (ARM will fault if you attempt to reference non 32bit aligned memory). Then hope you don't hit many issues where you get an invalid pointer that could be valid, as Sourav points out in the comment.

Option two is to use a static analysis tool, like Coverity, to check all the execution paths where you use uninitialized pointers. Depending on where you get the values, it may not be find problems.

Finally, since you're on bare metal, you can just override the fault handler. Been a while since I used STM32F4, but I remember you can override hard fault handlers, so it shouldn't be a problem. Then you set a global flag that you are testing the pointer, and dereference it. If it triggers the fault handler, check the flag - if it is set, just note that it is invalid and do nothing.

Example code:

```
volatile int faultTest;
volatile int faultHappened;

_Bool validatePointer(void *p)
{
    faultTest = 1;
    faultHappened = 0;
    int n = *(int*)p;
    faultTest = 0;

    return faultHappened;
}

void fault_handler(void)
{
    if (faultTest)
    {
        faultHappened = 1;
        return;
    }
    // regular fault code
}
```

Comment: Some ARMs allow unaligned accesses. And for some it is a configuration optin (IP or firmware). And there is no need to "override the fualt handler", but just to provide one. By default there will just be none.